# Using the same operator in two different streams in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to use the same operator in two different streams. However, I get an error that the UID or that operator is not unique.

```
lazy val opt: DataStream[Foo] => DataStream[Buzz] = src => src.flatMap(new MyFlatMapFunc).uid("opt")

lazy val pipe1 = : DataStream[Foo] => DataStream[Buzz] = src => opt(src). // Do keyBy and other logic

lazy val pipe2 = : DataStream[Foo] => DataStream[Buzz] = src => opt(src). // Do some other logic
```

I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Hash collision on user-specified ID "opt". Most likely cause is a non-unique ID. Please check that all IDs specified via `uid(String)` are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `uid` is on operator that will be used twice in the pipeline. You have two options, You can `union` both streams into one so that operator is used only once, or You can change the logic a little bit, so that you are assigning different ids:

```
lazy val opt: (DataStream[Foo], String) => DataStream[Buzz] = (src, id) => src.flatMap(new MyFlatMapFunc).uid(id)

lazy val pipe1 = : (DataStream[Foo], String) => DataStream[Buzz] = src => opt(src, "firstOpt"). // Do keyBy and other logic

lazy val pipe2 = : (DataStream[Foo], String) => DataStream[Buzz] = src => opt(src, "secondOpt"). // Do keyBy and other logic
```

Comment: Thanks, it is actually splitting the stream rather than `union` isn't it ? that operator is upstream. if I give it a different `uid` than I will get two operators which is nice when looking at the code but it is a waste of resources

Comment: The only way to avoid having two operators would be to merge the two streams, e.g., with `union`.

Comment: @igx it does not split them really ;) It's just two streams that will fully go through both  operators. If You want to split them, then You should probably think of some else method.